# How to pass method name as a parameter in PHP

Tags: php

In PHP, if method foo() calls method bar($name), can it pass it's method name (i.e. 'foo') as a parameter?

Comment: You realize that a method needs an object, right?

Comment: you meant a function, not a method right?. a method is basically a function which is a part of an object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use magic constant **FUNCTION**

```
 function foo(){
  bar(__FUNCTION__);
 }
```

Additionall use

```
 __METHOD__ to get the name of a method
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php